# evaluating $\int_{_C}cothz \,dz $ using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\int_{_C}cothz \,dz $ where $C$ is the Circle $|z| = 1$.

Now $cothz=\frac{cosh}{sinhz} $
And $coshz=\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}, sinhz=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}$. expanding $e^z=1+z+z^2/2+...$ and $e^{-z}=1-z+z^2/2-.....$

so $cothz=\frac{2+Z^2+...}{2Z+...}$. Now $Z=0$ is a pole of order 1.

So by cauchy residue theroem we get the value $2\pi i$

But the answer given is $0$

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Who gave a zero answer ?

Comment: the book from where i got the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now $cothz=\frac{coshz}{sinhz}$ And $coshz=\frac{e^z+e^{−z}}{2}$,$sinhz=\frac{e^z−e^{−z}}{2}$. expanding $e^z=1+z+z^2/2+... $and $e^{−z}=1−z+z^2/2−.....$
so $cothz=\frac{2+Z^2+...}{2Z+....}$ Now $Z=0$ is a pole of order 1.

So by cauchy residue theroem we get the value 2πi